# Using PROGMEM to store array of structs

Tags: flash, progmem, struct

I am hitting the limits of my arduino's SRAM and found that SRAM usage can be reduced by storing static stuff in flash memory instead of SRAM.

My project can (optionally) be built with an included SimulatorClass. I use this to 'playback' data at home which I gathered during real-life testing of my project. My project is based on photoelectric sensors, and it's timing-critical, so all timekeeping is done using `micros()`, which returns `unsigned long` datatype.

To simulate these photoelectric sensor triggers, I need an array containing a `struct` of 3 variables each:
unsigned int _iDataPos;

```
   struct SimulatorRecord
   {
      uint8_t iSensorNumber;
      unsigned long lTriggerTime;
      uint8_t iState;
   };
```

So one these structs is 6 bytes long in my counting (2x `uint8_t` = 2 bytes, `unsigned long` = 4 bytes).
A typical set of simulator records I need to use is about 25-30 records long, so worst case scenario the simulator array is 180 bytes in size.

I initialize these arrays like so:

```
SimulatorRecord SimulatorQueue[28] = {
      { 1, 41708, 1 }
      , { 2, 60692, 1 }
      , { 1, 176848, 0 }
      , { 2, 197732, 0 }
      , { 1, 4675580, 1 }
      , { 2, 4692252, 1 }
      , { 2, 4830180, 0 }
      , { 1, 4849032, 0 }
      , { 2, 9058416, 1 }
      , { 1, 9074780, 1 }
      , { 1, 9215868, 0 }
      , { 2, 9234968, 0 }
      , { 2, 13497276, 1 }
      , { 2, 13500924, 0 }
      , { 2, 13502728, 1 }
      , { 1, 13514992, 1 }
      , { 1, 13668000, 0 }
      , { 1, 13669344, 1 }
      , { 1, 13681828, 0 }
      , { 2, 13701464, 0 }
      , { 2, 18028788, 1 }
      , { 2, 18034252, 0 }
      , { 2, 18036540, 1 }
      , { 1, 18046892, 1 }
      , { 2, 18160312, 0 }
      , { 1, 18178224, 0 }
      , { 1, 20454580, 1 }
      , { 1, 20456368, 0 }
   };
```

In my simulator code I then loop through these arrays like so:

```
   unsigned int _iDataPos = 0;
   SimulatorRecord PendingRecord = SimulatorQueue[_iDataPos];

   //main simulator loop
   if (PendingRecord.lTriggerTime <= lRaceElapsedTime)
   {
      //simulate signal
      digitalWrite(PendingRecord.iSensorNumber, PendingRecord.iState);

      //And increase pending record
      _iDataPos++;
      PendingRecord = SimulatorQueue[_iDataPos];
   }
```

Now I've been reading various `PROGMEM` tutorials, and storing the `SimulatorQueue` array in flash seems to be piece of cake, just change

```
SimulatorRecord SimulatorQueue[28]
```

to

```
const PROGMEM SimulatorRecord SimulatorQueue[28]
```

But for the life of me I can't find out how I should change the copying of each array item to the `PendingRecord` variable, as my `iDataPos` counter increases.

Edit: I should have mentioned that this simulator class and all it's member functions & variables reside in a seperate *.cpp and *.h file.
I alreadt found out that since i'm initializing the `SimulatorQueue` array in the class itself, and not in the main *.ino file, I should do it like so:

```
constexpr static SimulatorRecord SimulatorQueue[28] PROGMEM = {<structs go in here>};
```

Edit2: Sample code which reproduces the problem when the simulator array is available here:
http://1drv.ms/1TRwiIB

Comment: I don't know why this only has one upvote, it's a very good question. (Ftr, I am that one upvoter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way of accessing any type of data in PROGMEM is to use this small library:

**PROGMEM_readAnything.h**

```C++
#include <Arduino.h>  // for type definitions

template <typename T> void PROGMEM_readAnything (const T * sce, T& dest)
  {
  memcpy_P (&dest, sce, sizeof (T));
  }

template <typename T> T PROGMEM_getAnything (const T * sce)
  {
  static T temp;
  memcpy_P (&temp, sce, sizeof (T));
  return temp;
  }
```

You can put that file into a new tab in your IDE, or make a library by putting it inside a folder called `PROGMEM_readAnything` and put that folder inside the `libraries` folder, which is inside your sketchbook folder.

That lets you copy from the memory in PROGMEM (using memcpy_P) into RAM. The template is used to work out how many bytes to copy.

---

Example, using your structure:

```C++
#include <PROGMEM_readAnything.h>

struct SimulatorRecord
{
  uint8_t iSensorNumber;
  unsigned long lTriggerTime;
  uint8_t iState;
};

const SimulatorRecord SimulatorQueue[28] PROGMEM = {
      { 1, 41708, 1 }
      , { 2, 60692, 1 }
      , { 1, 176848, 0 }
 //    ...   omitted for brevity
      , { 1, 18178224, 0 }
      , { 1, 20454580, 1 }
      , { 1, 20456368, 0 }
   };

// number of items in an array
template< typename T, size_t N > size_t ArraySize (T (&) [N]){ return N; }

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();

  for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize (SimulatorQueue); i++)
    {
    SimulatorRecord thisItem;
    PROGMEM_readAnything (&SimulatorQueue [i], thisItem);
    Serial.print (i);
    Serial.print (F(" = "));
    Serial.print (thisItem.iSensorNumber);
    Serial.print (F(" / "));
    Serial.print (thisItem.lTriggerTime);
    Serial.print (F(" / "));
    Serial.print (thisItem.iState);
    Serial.println ();
    }  // end of for loop
}  // end of setup

void loop ()
{
}  // end of loop
```

I found that it decreased RAM usage by 166 bytes, which is almost `28 * 6` (a couple of bytes must have been used by something).

---

#### Reference

[Putting constant data into program memory (PROGMEM)](http://www.gammon.com.au/progmem)

---

#### Putting PROGMEM into a class

In response to some comments below, this explains how to put the constants into a class.

Alex originally had:

```C++
class SimulatorClass
{

...

   typedef struct SimulatorRecord
   {
      uint8_t iSensorNumber;
      unsigned long lTriggerTime;
      uint8_t iState;
   } SimulatorRecord;

   constexpr static SimulatorRecord SimulatorQueue[28] PROGMEM = {
      { 1, 41708, 1 }
      , { 2, 60692, 1 }
   //    ...   omitted for brevity
      , { 1, 20454580, 1 }
      , { 1, 20456368, 0 }
   };

   SimulatorRecord PendingRecord;
};
```

Putting aside whatever "constexpr" is, you can't put constants inside a class like that. You need to make it static, and have the actual definition elsewhere. So, change the constants to:

```C++
class SimulatorClass
{

...

   typedef struct SimulatorRecord
   {
      uint8_t iSensorNumber;
      unsigned long lTriggerTime;
      uint8_t iState;
   } SimulatorRecord;

  static const SimulatorRecord SimulatorQueue[28] PROGMEM ;

  SimulatorRecord PendingRecord;
};
```

Now in your main class file (Simulator.cpp in your case):

```C++
 const SimulatorClass::SimulatorRecord SimulatorClass::SimulatorQueue[28] PROGMEM = {
    { 1, 41708, 1 }
    , { 2, 60692, 1 }
   //    ...   omitted for brevity
    , { 1, 20454580, 1 }
    , { 1, 20456368, 0 }
   };
```

That now compiles OK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it gives me the same compiler error as I commented on Ignaio's answer below.  I believe it has something to do with these being member functions and variables of a class, in a seperate cpp/h file. However I can't find how I should initialize `PendingRecord` correctly so it compiles...

Comment: Can you post the exact error message please? My code doesn't have SimulatorClass in it, so that cannot be in the error. I tested my code, I didn't just write it without trying. `it gives me the same compiler error` - I would like you to try my exact code. If `it` does not give a compiler error, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Nick your code works fine off course, but due to the nature of my project  I have to adapt it into my existing codebase. I committed my attempt at integrating your solution to Github, you can find it here: https://github.com/vyruz1986/FlyballSensor/tree/develop. It would be great if you could modify your answer with information on how to use your solution inside a class.

Comment: Can you modify your question to add a minimal example of what you are doing? There's a lot of code on your Github site. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be great.

Comment: OK sorry for that. Answer updated, check http://1drv.ms/1TRwiIB. Thanks!

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: Works perfectly, not a byte more SRAM usage compared to when I leave the whole SimulatorClass out! Thanks a million!

Comment: "whatever "constexpr" is" [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) is a very useful feature of C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Using it with heterogeneous types is trickier, since it has to be copied by hand instead of using one of the `pgm_read_*()` macros.

```
SimulatorRecord PendingRecord;
memcpy_P(&PendingRecord, &SimulatorQueue[_iDataPos], sizeof(PendingRecord));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! It is compiling but my SRAM usage isn't being affected at all. I also can't test if it works or not since my program is crashing due not enough SRAM... Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Never mind found it: was using `const SimulatorRecord SimulatorQueue[28] PROGMEM`, forgot to add the `static` keyword. I do get a compilation error on the `memcpy_P()` now however: `undefined reference to SimulatorClass::SimulatorQueue`

Comment: Could these `undefined reference to` errors be related to the fact the simulator class and its members reside in seperate cpp/h files? I edited my questions to clarify this.